migration to sql failed using prisma
When i using in local db and localhost the migration is succuussfully worked.
but when i deploy the server db. the migration is failed
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

// Looking for ways to speed up your queries, or scale easily with your serverless or edge functions?
// Try Prisma Accelerate: https://pris.ly/cli/accelerate-init

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
 // shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
 
}

enum Role {
  ADMIN
  COACH
  CLEINT
}

model User {
  id                  Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  email               String
  profile             Profile?
  role                Role                 @default(CLEINT)
  createdAt           DateTime             @default(now())
  updatedAt           DateTime             @updatedAt
  underCoach          Int?
  coach               User?                @relation("CoachToUser", fields: [underCoach], references: [id])
  clients             User[]               @relation("CoachToUser")
  connectRequestsFrom ConnectRequest[]     @relation("ConnectRequestFrom")
  connectRequestsTo   ConnectRequest[]     @relation("ConnectRequestTo")
  meal                Meal[]
  MealAssignment      MealAssignment[]
  // setByUser           MealTime[]       @relation("setBy")
  // setToUser           MealTime[]       @relation("setTo")
  WorkoutsAssignment  WorkoutsAssignment[]
  Workouts            Workouts[]
}

model Profile {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  dob         String
  gender      Gender   @default(MALE)
  height      Int?
  weight      Int?
  sugar       Int?
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  userId      Int      @unique
  user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  coachTypeId Int?
  coach       Coach?   @relation(fields: [coachTypeId], references: [id])
}

enum Gender {
  MALE
  FEMALE
  TRANSGENDER
}

model Coach {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  coachName String    @unique
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
  profile   Profile[]
}

model ConnectRequest {
  id        Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  fromId    Int
  toId      Int
  status    RequestStatus @default(PENDING)
  from      User          @relation("ConnectRequestFrom", fields: [fromId], references: [id])
  to        User          @relation("ConnectRequestTo", fields: [toId], references: [id])
  createdAt DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime      @updatedAt
}

enum RequestStatus {
  PENDING
  ACCEPTED
  REJECTED
}

model Meal {
  id             Int              @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name           String
  protiens       Int
  fats           Int
  carbs          Int
  mealType       MealType
  // mealPlan  MealPlan[] @relation("meals")
  createdAt      DateTime         @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime         @updatedAt
  userId         Int
  user           User?            @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  MealAssignment MealAssignment[]
}

model MealAssignment {
  id        Int      @id
  userId    Int // Adding userId directly instead of using @relation
  mealId    Int // Adding mealId directly instead of using @relation
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  meal      Meal     @relation(fields: [mealId], references: [id])
  day       Int // Day number for which the meal is assigned
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

enum MealType {
  BREAKFAST
  LUNCH
  DINNER
  SNACK
}

model MealTime {
  id        Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  setBy     Int
  setTo     Int
  whichMeal MealType
  time      String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model WorkoutsAssignment {
  id              Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  assigneddUserId Int
  workoutId       Int
  user            User     @relation(fields: [assigneddUserId], references: [id])
  workout         Workouts @relation(fields: [workoutId], references: [id])
  day             Int
  completed       Boolean  @default(false)
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Workouts {
  id                 Int                  @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name               String
  vcLink             String?
  createdUserId      Int
  user               User                 @relation(fields: [createdUserId], references: [id])
  createdAt          DateTime             @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime             @updatedAt
  WorkoutsAssignment WorkoutsAssignment[]
}


i run the cmd of npx prisma migrate dev
the error shows this
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "dev-fitish-v2" at "***n.com:25060"

Error: P3014

Prisma Migrate could not create the shadow database. Please make sure the database user has permission to create databases. Read more about the shadow database (and workarounds) at https://pris.ly/d/migrate-shadow

Original error: Error code: P1010

User `fitish` was denied access on the database `dev-fitish-v2`

if i run the cmd of npx prisma db push 
the error showsm like this..
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "dev-fitish-v2" at "***n.com:25060"
Error: REFERENCES command denied to user 'fitish'@'*.*.*.*' for table 'dev-fitish-v2.User'
   0: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::migration_step
           with step=AddForeignKey { foreign_key_id: ForeignKeyId(0) }
             at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/apply_migration.rs:21
   1: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::apply_migration
             at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/apply_migration.rs:10
   2: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:433

how to resolve this....
i want to migrate the schema model in my server db succussfully

user fitish doesn't have enough permissions to database, you got to grant permission for REFERENCES command; btw. don't give all your database data like that, it's dangerous

Why did you comment out the shadow database setting?
The shadow database is a database that has the same schema/structure as your database. If you change the prisma.schema file and run the migrate command, it will compare your database with the shadow database, and then it will create a migration SQL file.
You need to create a shadow database in your database server with the name <your-db-name>-shadow, and remove the comment mark for the shadow database setting.
please run following 2 commands one by one.
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only
npx prisma migrate deploy

The first command will create an SQL file containing the SQL commands for migration, and the second command will apply that SQL file to your real database.

I think your Prisma database user (fitish) does not have the right to create new databases on his own.
To my understanding Prisma needs two databases to ensure data consistency (at least in development):

the main database and
a shadow database (basically a copy of the main database)
I think Primas uses the shadow database internally to validate changes like migrations and schema changes before applying them to the main database.

Since I didn't want to give Prisma unlimited rights, I manually created two separate databases and configure Prisma as follow (schema.prisma):
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider          = "mysql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}
// ...

and I gave Prisma the rights it needs but just for both databases.
Here are detailed instructions about the shadow database | Prisma Documentation. I hope it helps a little.

I also note you can't use custom schema names, so just use default (leave schema absent in db URL or set schema to dbo) @see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17574#issuecomment-1406507637
